# Is there a way to force a flow to do an update and then continue to the next element?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, flow-builder

I have a requirement in the Salesforce flow to update a particular contact record twice. The two update elements are consecutive that is after one update it goes to the other. But I have a requirement to first commit the changes in the first one and then execute the second update. Due to Salesforce bulkification the two updates happen in one commit. Please let me know if there is any way to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three basic options. First, you can use a Pause with a zero hour delay, which pauses and immediately unpauses the interview in a new transaction. Second, in the Update Records element, you can open the Advanced section, where you'll find the transaction control option. The default is to let Salesforce decide (which is almost always to keep going), or you can manually override to specify a new transaction. This is only available in some flows. Third, you can use a Scheduled Path, available only in certain types of flows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where can I access the advanced section it doesnt show any such link on the element for me

Comment: @MuhammedRishdhi I just realized that I was unclear. Transaction control is not available in all types of flows. You may need to use a Pause or a Scheduled Path, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update !